# does facebook support xrds or openid endpoint discovery?

Tags: openid, facebook-oauth, xrds

By requesting a special mime type called application/xrds+xml when performing an HTTP GET on the identity URL,  developers can choose which of the alternatives to implement.

Is this possible with facebook ( as against using facebook connect )

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly not documented if they do. Undocumented features are poor to rely on.